# Javascript - Remove object from nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of objects, each object must have key and title, but children is optional, and it can be nested, i can have children inside of children many times. I want to remove some object by provided key value (for example key 677). I tried with filter but i only remove first level. Also have tried recursion, but not sure if i did it right.

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1',
    title: 'title 1',
    children: [{
      key: '098',
      title: 'hey',
      children: [{
        key: '677',
        title: 'child'
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    key: '123',
    title: 'tile 111'
  },
  {
    key: '345',
    title: 'something'
  }
];

const rem = '677';

const del = (el) => {
  if (!el.children) {
    return el.key !== rem;
  } else {
    if (el.key !== rem) {
      del(el.children);
      return el;
    }
  }
};
const res = data.filter((el) => {
  return del(el);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: 1. there is a syntax error with the first children - children is array right now.
2. post your desirable result.

Comment: Your top level `children` is an array of objects, so add curly braces

Comment: Have you tried any recursive solutions?  Would also be nice if you posted the filter code that only worked on the first level.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your existing solution is like

```
const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    title: 'title 1',
    children: [{
      key: '098',
      title: 'hey',
      children: [{ key: '677', title: 'child'}]
    }]
  },
  { key: '123', title: 'tile 111' },
  { key: '345', title: 'something' }
];

function removeByKey(arr, removingKey){
  return arr.filter( a => a.key !== removingKey);
}
```

So it works on the first level but not deeply.

Just change it like that will do the jobs

```
function removeByKey(arr, removingKey){
  return arr.filter( a => a.key !== removingKey).map( e => {
    return { ...e, children: removeByKey(e.children || [], removingKey)}
  });
}
```

Little warning, children property will not be set to [] for every item not having any children.

So how it works? Well instead of keeping acceptable items as they are, we make a copy using `{...e}` that's equivalent to `{key:e.key, title:e.title, children:e.children}` in this case.

We know force to override the property children with `removeByKey(e.children || [], removingKey)`, so we call the method recursively. Not the function works deeeply.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a recursion approach with findIndex and splice. Using `some` will allow the code to exit without running through the entire tree.

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1',
    title: 'title 1',
    children: [{
      key: '098',
      title: 'hey',
      children: [{
        key: '677',
        title: 'child'
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    key: '123',
    title: 'tile 111'
  },
  {
    key: '345',
    title: 'something'
  }
];

const removeKey = (data, key) => {
  // look to see if object exists
  const index = data.findIndex(x => x.key === key);
  if (index > -1) {
    data.splice(index, 1); // remove the object
    return true
  } else {
    // loop over the indexes of the array until we find one with the key
    return data.some(x => {
      if (x.children) {
        return removeKey(x.children, key);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(removeKey(data, '677'))
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: there couldn't a data with index similar to a different child in a different index of it's ancestor?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple recursion to do the trick:

```
const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    title: 'title 1',
    children: [
     {
      key: '098',
      title: 'hey',
      children: [{ key: '677', title: 'child'}]
     }
    ]
  },
  { key: '123', title: 'tile 111' },
  { key: '345', title: 'something' }
];

function removeByKey(key, arr) {
  // loop through all items of array
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // if array item has said key, then remove it
    if(arr[i].key === key) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    } else if(typeof(arr[i].children) !== "undefined") {
      // if object doesn't have desired key but has children, call this function 
      // on the children array
      removeByKey(key, arr[i].children);
    }
  }
}

removeByKey('098', data);

console.log(data);
```

This may be a little easier to understand than the other answer provided.